# Shell script to Preprocess Fortran RECORDs to TYPEs?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, fortran

I'm converting some old F77 code to compile under gfortran.  I have a bunch of RECORDS used in the following manner:

```
RecoRD /TEST/ this
this.field = 1
this.otherfield.sumthin = 2
func = func(%val(ThIs.field,foo.bar,this.other.field))
```

I am trying to convert these all to TYPEs as such:

```
TYPE(TEST) this
this%field = 1
this%otherfield%sumthin = 2
func = func(%val(ThIs%field,foo.bar,this%other%field))
```

I'm just ok with sed and I can process the files to replace the RECORD declarations with TYPE declarations, but is there a way to write a preprocessing type of script using linux tools to convert the this.field notation to this%field notation?  I believe I would need something that can recognize the declared record name and target it specifically to avoid borking other variables on accident.  Also, any idea how I can deal with included files?  I feel like that could get pretty messy but if anyone has done something similar it would be good to include in a solution.

Edit:
I have python 2.4 avaialable to me.

Comment: i'd think to be safe you should read the associated STRUCTURE and do replacements based on matching both variable and valid field names. I'd sugest using a higher language than sed, python for example.  STRUCTURE/RECORD is an extension, not standard f77 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Python for that. Following script reads the text from stdin and outputs it to stdout using the replacement you asked for:

```
import re
import sys

txt = sys.stdin.read()
names = re.findall(r"RECORD /TEST/\s*\b(.+)\b", txt, re.MULTILINE)
for name in list(set(names)):
    txt = re.sub(r"\b%s\.(.*)\b"%name, r"%s%%\1"%name, txt, 
                 re.MULTILINE)
sys.stdout.write(txt)
```

EDIT: As for Python 2.4: Yes format should be replaced with %. As for structures with subfields, one could easily achieve that by using a function in the `sub()` call as below. I also added case insensitiveness:

```
import re
import sys

def replace(match):
    return match.group(0).replace(".", "%")

txt = sys.stdin.read()
names = re.findall(r"RECORD /TEST/\s*\b(.+)\b", txt, re.MULTILINE)
for name in names:
    txt = re.sub(r"\b%s(\.\w+)+\b" % name, replace, txt,
                 re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
sys.stdout.write(txt)
```

Comment: This looks really promising!  I hadn't even thought about doing it in python.  Off the top of my head I have a few clarifications to the question;  records can be multi-level, ie this.obj.rec -> this%obj%rec  ; the matches have to be case insensitive  ; the RECORD statement has to also be converted to a TYPE statement;  I am using python 2.4 so .format isn't available.  Will edit your answer as I figure things out.

Comment: I updated my post, that one should work for arbitrary number of levels.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/RECORD/ { $0 = gensub(/[^/]+[/]([^/]+)[/]/,"TYPE(\\1)",""); name=tolower($NF) }
{
   while ( match(tolower($0),"\\<" name "[.][[:alnum:]_.]+") ) {
      $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) \
           gensub(/[.]/,"%","g",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)) \
           substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
}
{ print }

$ cat file
RECORD /TEST/ tHiS
this.field = 1
THIS.otherfield.sumthin = 2
func = func(%val(ThIs.field,foo.bar,this.other.field))

$ awk -f tst.awk file
TYPE(TEST) tHiS
this%field = 1
THIS%otherfield%sumthin = 2
func = func(%val(ThIs%field,foo.bar,this%other%field))
```

Note that I modified your input to show what would happen with multiple occurrences of `this.field` on one line and mixed in with other "." references (`foo.bar`). I also added some mixed-case occurrences of "this" to show how that works.

In response to the question below about how to handle included files, here's one way:

This script will not only expand all the lines that say "include subfile", but by writing the result to a tmp file, resetting ARGV[1] (the highest level input file) and not resetting ARGV[2] (the tmp file), it then lets awk do any normal record parsing on the result of the expansion since that's now stored in the tmp file. If you don't need that, just do the "print" to stdout and remove any other references to a tmp file or ARGV[2].

```
awk 'function read(file) {
       while ( (getline < file) > 0) {
           if ($1 == "include") {
                read($2)
           } else {
                print > ARGV[2]
           }
       }
       close(file)
   }
   BEGIN{
      read(ARGV[1])
      ARGV[1]=""
      close(ARGV[2])
   }1' a.txt tmp
```

The result of running the above given these 3 files in the current directory:

```
  a.txt             b.txt              c.txt
  -----             -----              -----
  1                 3                  5
  2                 4                  6
  include b.txt     include c.txt
  9                 7
  10                8
```

would be to print the numbers 1 through 10 and save them in a file named "tmp".

So for this application you could replace the number "1" at the end of the above script with the contents of the first script posted above and it'd work on the tmp file that now includes the contents of the expanded files.

Comment: I was thinking that in order to isolate "this." it may be as simple as only allowing a certain set of characters to preceded "this.", such as "(", "\n", whitespace, etc..  I haven't been able to find an "accepted" set of such characters yet.  I also updated the q with more precise constraints.

Comment: Looks solid. It's going to take me some time to decipher what your script is doing... I'll come back to it on my lunch break!  Is there any way to handle included files with awk or would that be best addressed via a higher level script that might serve to call your awk script?

Comment: You can do it by expanding them with a function. I'll update my answer to show one way to do that in general.

Comment: I think the base awk script will work well, but I made the following changes to retain leading whitespace and to ignore case on the match: tolower($0) ~ /record/ { $0 = gensub(/([[:space:]]+)[^/]+[/]([^/]+)[/]/,"\\1TYPE(\\2)",""); name=tolower($NF) } ... the mysteries of awk are slowly unraveling.

Comment: change `[[:space:]]+` to `^[[:space:]]*` to make sure it just matches LEADING white space and it accommodates the case where there is no leading space.

Comment: Right on.  There will always be leading whitespace since this is fortran 77 but the addition couldn't hurt.